# Why when uploading a csv to mysql, data changes order?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Why when uploading a csv to mysql, data changes order ?

I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE earthquakes (
 idserial VARCHAR(30),
 milliseconds BIGINT,
 latitude FLOAT,
 longitude FLOAT,
 magnitude FLOAT,
 ipocentro FLOAT,
 source VARCHAR(4),
 region SMALLINT,
 PRIMARY KEY(idserial),
 INDEX indice_milliseconds(milliseconds),
 INDEX indice_lat_lng(latitude,longitude),
 INDEX indice_magnitude(magnitude),
 INDEX indice_ipocentro(ipocentro)
);
```

In my `csv` file data is are in this order:

```
"1900-07-29-1-0",-2190913260000,-10,165,7.6,0,"U",184
"1900-10-09-1-0",-2184672720000,60,-142,7.7,0,"U",19
"1900-10-29-1-0",-2182952940000,11,-66,7.7,0,"U",94
"1901-08-09-1-0",-2158405140000,-22,170,7.9,0,"U",189
"1901-08-09-2-0",-2158385220000,40,144,7.5,0,"U",229
"1902-04-19-1-0",-2136584220000,14,-91,7.5,0,"U",70
"1902-08-22-1-0",-2125782000000,40,77,7.7,0,"U",320
"1902-09-22-2-0",-2123108040000,18,146,7.5,0,"U",216
"1902-09-23-1-0",-2122954920000,16,-93,7.8,0,"U",61
"1903-01-14-1-0",-2113254780000,15,-98,7.7,0,"U",66
"1904-06-25-1-0",-2067592461000,51.565,161.417,7.5,15,"U",219
```

The records are sorted from the oldest date to the most recent. But after loading is so:

```
"1904-06-25-1-0",-2067592461000,51.565,161.417,7.5,15,"U",219
"1903-01-14-1-0",-2113254780000,15,-98,7.7,0,"U",66
"1902-09-23-1-0",-2122954920000,16,-93,7.8,0,"U",61
"1902-09-22-2-0",-2123108040000,18,146,7.5,0,"U",216
"1902-08-22-1-0",-2125782000000,40,77,7.7,0,"U",320
"1902-04-19-1-0",-2136584220000,14,-91,7.5,0,"U",70
"1900-07-29-1-0",-2190913260000,-10,165,7.6,0,"U",184
"1900-10-09-1-0",-2184672720000,60,-142,7.7,0,"U",19
"1900-10-29-1-0",-2182952940000,11,-66,7.7,0,"U",94
"1901-08-09-1-0",-2158405140000,-22,170,7.9,0,"U",189
"1901-08-09-2-0",-2158385220000,40,144,7.5,0,"U",229
```

They doesn't respect the initial order....

Could be that i have like `PRIMARY KEY` the field `idserial` (first value) that is a string (unique) and not numeric value with autoincrement ?

Comment: The order of data in a table is completely meaningless unless you select from it with an ORDER BY clause - when you do so and `ORDER BY DateTimeColName` everything will be as you want (assuming the column is correctly sett as a datetime type).

Comment: @AlexK. and if i would to extract last 10 records, in query i have to specify an ORDER BY ?

Comment: Yes - because "last" doesn't mean anything without an ORDER BY to tell the database what to sort into first to last order.

Comment: @AlexK. but if i add an ID (like primary key) maybe the order it will be the same of csv ?

Comment: @Borja - not guaranteed, unless you apply an `ORDER BY id` clause.... SQL gives __no guarantees__ about order in which records are returned, unless you explicitly specify an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Yes i understand you....however now i tried to add ID like primary key and the order didn't change (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want data in a particular order, then you need an `order by` clause when you query the table.

If you want to add an auto-incremented id column (which I recommend), then you can have that column preserve the original ordering in the CSV file.  Just create the table with that column and list all other columns in the `load data` statement.

Comment: The problem is that "idserial" (that is string value) is unique for each record, so is like an "id autoincrement". My table is too big (8 fields with 4 index and over 1000000 records). If i add also id and other index for "idserial" the table increase yet

Comment: @Borja . . . If you are worried about an index on a table with a million rows, then you are either in a severely resource limited environment (I'm thinking Apple Watch) or don't understand databases.

Comment: Both things :D now i tried to add ID like primary key and the order didn't change (Y)

Comment: @Borja . . . You need to `order by` the id, when you query the table.

Comment: yes yes but i say that when i open mysql and there's not "order by", data are same order like csv. Obviously when i will extract data i use "order by" :)

Comment: @Borja . . . Correct.  The table represents an *unordered* set.  If you want to see particular rows, you need a `SELECT` query.